# How can I achieve this specific output using for loops to simplify storing data in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

```
   public class IndividualProject2 {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
     int i;
    for( i = 0; i < 7; i++){
        Scanner gradeInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter midterm 1 score: ");
        int num1 = gradeInput.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter midterm 2 score: ");
        int num2 = gradeInput.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter final score: ");
        int num3 = gradeInput.nextInt();
    }


}

 public static char function (int grade){
    String[] name = new String[7];
    char[] finalGrade = new char[7];
    char letter;
    if (grade >= 90){
        letter = 'A';   
        System.out.println(letter);
    }
    else if (grade >= 80 && grade < 90){
        letter = 'B';            
        System.out.println(letter);
    }
    else if(grade >= 70 && grade < 80){
        letter = 'C';               
        System.out.println(letter);
    }
    else{
        letter = 'F';               
        System.out.println(letter);
    }
    for(int counter=0; counter < finalGrade.length; counter++ ){
        finalGrade[counter] = letter;
    }
    return letter;

    }

  public static int function (int midtermOne, int midtermTwo) {
    int result;
    int[] midterm = new int[7];
    if ( midtermOne > midtermTwo)
    {
        result = midtermOne;
    }
    else{
        result = midtermTwo;
    }
    for(int counter=0; counter < midterm.length; counter++ ){
        midterm[counter] = result;
    }
    return result;
    }
 public static double function (int num1, int num2, int num3){
    double result; 
    double[] average = new double[7];
    result = (num1 + num2 + num3)/3.0;
    for(int counter=0; counter < average.length; counter++ ){
        average[counter] = result;
   }
    return result;
    }
     }
```

**The output should look like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3Mjr.png**
I am having difficulty creating a loop that match this specific output.How do I take the inputs in the the loop while using the three function methods to store the values in the arrays. I feel very overwhelmed on how to do this.

Comment: Side note: in Java you really rarely need to use arrays. Use `List` instead.

Comment: How far along in class are you?  Are you allowed to use java Collections (e.g. java.util.List) - are you allowed to use additional Classes?

Comment: Sounds to me like you need to create a Student Class.

Comment: We haven't covered those yet unfortunately. We've only gone up to method overloading.

Comment: What about ArrayLists

Comment: Haven't covered those either, the farthest we've covered in those is just initializing them and creating them. This is why I find the assignment frustrating. I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Move `Scanner gradeInput = new Scanner(System.in);` before the `for` loop in your `main`. In this way you can avoid doing the same thing `7` times which is not useful in anyway.

Declare four arrays - `name`, `midTerm1`, `midTerm2` and `avg` for holding `4` values for each student. You can define them at the `class` level or inside `main`.

Fill these four arrays for each student something like

```
for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
    System.out.println("Student number " + (i + 1) );
    System.out.print("Enter student's name:  ");
    name[i] = gradeInput.next();
    System.out.print("Enter midterm 1 score: ");
    midTerm1[i] = gradeInput.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter midterm 2 score: ");
    midTerm2[i] = gradeInput.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter final score:     ");
    avg[i] = gradeInput.nextInt();
}
```

Once, this is done do as below

```
System.out.printf("%-8s %6s %8s %8s\n", "name", "final", "midterm", "average");
for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    System.out.printf("%-8s %6c %8d %2.6f\n", name[i] , function(avg[i]), function(md1[i], md2[i]), function(md1[i], md2[i], avg[i]));
}
```

Remove all the `print` statements from `function (int grade)`.

**One side note** It is also possible not to hard code the value for number of students - in your case `7` and pass it from command line. In this case, you can use that number to initialize all the four arrays sizes and modify the `for` loops appropriately.

For example - inside `main`, you can do something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   int noOfStudents;
   if (args.length == 1) {
       noOfStudents = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
       name = new String[noOfStudents];
       midTerm1 = new int[noOfStudents];
       midTerm2 = new int[noOfStudents];
       avg = new int[noOfStudents];
   } else {
       System.out.println("please provide a value for no of students data that need to be processed");
       return;
   }
}
```